# Unable to list applications from Azure Active Directory using Powershell in Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I have created an Automation Account runbook with Powershell 5.1 .
I have a service principal with the following permissions linked to it using a connection called "local"

[image]

My code is as follows :

```
    $connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "local"
    try {
    Write-Output 'Connecting to services'
    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $connection.TenantID -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-null
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
    Disconnect-AzureAD | Out-null
    Break
}

Write-Output "Connect process done"
# Function
try {
    Write-Output 'List all apps'
    $list = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
 $true
    Write-Output $list
}
Catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
    Disconnect-AzureAD
}
```

When I run the code I am getting the following error :

[image]

```
Error occurred while executing GetApplications Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

I am not sure why my permission is not working, how do I resolve this ?

Edit:
I granted the service principal Directory Read permission but I am getting a new error.
Permissions:
[image]

Error:
[image]

```
Error occurred while executing GetApplications Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to list applications from Azure Active Directory using PowerShell in Azure Automation Account.

When I attempted to run the `PowerShell script` in `Automation account` with the `'Application.Read.All'` permission, I encountered the same error

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "TenantId" -ApplicationId "Application-ID" -CertificateThumbprint "849EAFE0fhgjgjgjgggg7340B789221D0E"
$list = Get-AzureADApplication
$list.DisplayName
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the issue, I assigned the `Azure AD` role of `Directory Readers` to my `Service Principal` and ran the `Automation` account, expecting the desired result.

**Directory Readers**

[image]

Assigned `Directory Readers` role to `Service Principal`

[image]

Once I assigned the role to my `service principal`, I got the expected result

[image]

Reference: [Azure AD Graph Retirement and Powershell Module Deprecation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/important-azure-ad-graph-retirement-and-powershell-module/ba-p/3848270#:%7E:text=We%20plan%20to%20deprecate%20Azure,to%20Microsoft%20Graph%20PowerShell%20SDK.)

Comment: I tried adding the Directory Role but I am getting a new permissions error , not sure what went wrong

Comment: I understood where I was going wrong , I was trying to assign Graph API instead of Directory permission. Thanks!